# FirebaseInstanceId.Instance is returning null

Tags: visual-studio, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to get fcm token in my xamarin.android project.
Nugets I am using

```html
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Common" version="71.1610.0" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Core" version="71.1601.0" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid" version="71.1710.0" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid.Interop" version="71.1601.0" targetFramework="monoandroid90" />
```

Code For retrieving the token

```
FirebaseInstanceId instance = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
Android.Gms.Tasks.Task instanceId = instance.GetInstanceId();
instanceId.AddOnSuccessListener(this, this);
```

But `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance` is always null

Comment: Have you added a google-services.json file to your project?

Comment: Yes it is added

Comment: First of all, please update your VS version to the latest. Then set the targeting framework to 9.0(API 28).And operate a full clean and rebuild is required after adding the google-services.json file and setting it as a GoogleServicesJson build action.

Comment: Thank @LeonLu-MSFT , will try and see if this works, but my google-services.json file already has the same build action. Crashlytics works properly the issue is only with the firebaseinstanceId

Comment: Ok, watting for your update.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT the solution didn't work. I will now try to downgrade the versions as suggested by woj and see

Comment: Ok, please try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lucky, because just recently I have came across the same issue. I assume you also use Xamarin.Firebase.Auth and all related packages to it. There is an issue with the newest version, for some reason Xamarin.Firebase.Auth and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging don't like each other. Downgrade both version to 60.1142.1 (you will have to downgrade GoogleService.Base to the lower version, I would personally remove both packages first and re-add them using version 60.1142.1). 
This fixed my issue with it, which weirdly on my Xamarin on Mac resulted in push notification not working, but on windows version the Instance was null.